# Finding details about HTTP error 400

Tags: apex, api, error

I am trying to implement some functionality with DatedCoversionDate object. Unfortunately it is not possible to change it with DML but there is a way to use API calls.

here is an example

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/DatedConversionRate/');
req.setBody('{ "IsoCode" : "UAH", "ConversionRate" : 24.55, "StartDate" : "2019-12-11" }');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Cookie', 'debug_logs=1');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

In general, it works fine. But during development there are sometimes errors and I get the next response:

16:53:23:207 USER_DEBUG [39]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

Which is really not much useful. Is there a way to find some more information what went wrong on the server during the call?  Because now I have to guess and that takes really a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the currency rates for the given date, you would get the HTTP 400 error when trying to create it again.

Comment: yes, thanks. 
That was the case, which I found by a method of trials.

But is there a way to find more information than just HTTP 400 response

Comment: ```HttpResponse.getBody()``` will reveal the actual message that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That's exactly what I was looking for.